# Python bankaccount class error

Tags: python-2.7

```
class BankAccount: 
    def __init__(self,  balance, MinimumBalanceAccount):
        """Creates an account with the given balance."""
        self.money = balance 
        self.penalty = 0
        self.balance = balance
        self.MInimumBalanceAccount = MinimumBalanceAccount

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Deposits the amount into the account."""
        self.money += amount
        return self.money

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.money - amount < 0:
           self.money -= amount+5
           self.penalty += 5

        else:
           self.money -= amount
        return self.money


    def get_balance(self):
        """Returns the current balance in the account."""
        return self.money

    def get_fees(self):
        """Returns the total fees ever deducted from the account."""
        return self.penalty

class MinimumBalanceAccountsub_class(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, name, minimum):
       self.name = name
       self.minimum = minimum
```

I am trying to run the program but an internal error displays with the following syntax Internal Error:

```
>  runTests aborted: TestOutcomeEvent(handled=False, test=, result=,
> outcome='error', exc_info=(, TypeError('__init__() takes exactly 3
> arguments (2 given)',), ), reason=None, expected=False,
> shortLabel=None, longLabel=None) is not JSON serializable
```

Can any one help me how can I fix it?

Comment: okay i have tried to run your revision it still produces the following, and it is a test i was given.Could it be the problem of the compiler..

Comment: The test code looks like this with the Question. Create a class called BankAccount

    Create a constructor that takes in an integer and assigns this to a `balance` property.
    Create a method called `deposit` that takes in cash deposit amount and updates the balance accordingly.
    Create a method called `withdraw` that takes in cash withdrawal amount and updates the balance accordingly. if amount is greater than balance return `"invalid transaction"`
    Create a subclass MinimumBalanceAccount of the BankAccount class

Comment: The test code looks like this

Comment: def test_balance(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.balance, 90, msg='Account Balance Invalid')
    
  def test_deposit(self):
    self.my_account.deposit(90)
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.balance, 180, msg='Deposit method inaccurate')
    
  def test_withdraw(self):
    self.my_account.withdraw(40)
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.balance, 50, msg='Withdraw method inaccurate')
    
  def test_invalid_operation(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.withdraw(1000), "invalid transaction", msg='Invalid transaction')

Comment: finally debugged up to here is my final error, TypeError('_init_()takes exactly 3 arguments (2given)'),),

Comment: any one who can assist?

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError('*init*()takes exactly 3 arguments (2given)'),)

The error occurred because the third argument **money** was not specified in your constructor . The following should solve the issue

> `def __init__(self, money, balance, MinimumBalanceAccount):
>           """Creates an account with the given balance."""
>           self.money = balance 
>           self.penalty = 0
>           self.balance = balance
>           self.MInimumBalanceAccount = MinimumBalanceAccount`